# help designing autocomplete response's

Tags: asp.net, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I want my autocomplete to be very user friendly.

I have products that people will search for by:

```
part#
manufacturer
```

e.g. searches

```
HND123

Honda 123
```

So basically each manufacturer has a short form and a long form.

How should I build my search index so when the autocomplete needs to fetch the data from the db, it will return results for both types of queries?

Answer (score 1):

I would do this as a UNION, even if you have the same table. Assuming that you are searching in two different columns.

`SELECT PartNumber AS Term FROM Parts WHERE PartNumber LIKE 'input%'`
`UNION`
`SELECT Manufaturer AS Term FROM Parts WHERE Manufactuer LIKE 'input%`